# How do you disable an app on chrome OS with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-os

I am a bit more experienced with making games than interacting with files in ways this significant. I am trying to make a little GUI that can disable an app (on Chrome OS) and re-enable it. I have been trying to come up with ways I could do this, but I found out all of those wouldn't work (Due to some sort of concept in js that unhelpfully prevents what I'm doing). The thing I could come up with was the HTML (Which also... may/will not work... ):

```
<div class="GUI-Container">
  <form action="script.js"> <!--Or a js function. I am not that experienced with forms-->
    <label>
      Turn:
      <input type="radio" name="turnOff/On" value="On">On</input>
      <input type="radio" name="turnOff/On" value="Off">Off</input>
    </label>
    <input type="submit">Go</input>
  </form>
</div>
```

Hopefully JS works with the action attribute. If not, well, then this form is useless and I will have to try something else. I just need the js code and maybe improvments on the HTML code because I have very minimal experience with forms. Like I said, I am more of a game designer.

Comment: are you running this code in the browser?

Comment: In Chrome? yes. I will test the code in Chrome when I get any suggestions on what the rest of the code may be. I just want to know if there is a way to disable apps on Chrome OS via JS.

Comment: No. There is no way. Webpages and browser extensions can not interact with the OS or the applications on the computer. They are only given access to whatever the browser exposes to them. It would be a pretty big security vulnerability otherwise. Can you imagine a random website disabling your antivirus, your motherboard processes such as fan control etc. ? That would be catastrophic

Comment: Ok, any way to disable a browser extension?

Comment: Not from a web page. A web page can not alter the browser state or settings. Last time i checked an extension could disable another extension using https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management but it might have been removed since then, you will need to check